# Visual Basic , reading in certain integers

Tags: vb6

So I am writing code that will read in weather data from a file. What I have now is a function that can read it in if there is only integers in the file and nothing to label it. Here is an example of my file:

```
January
2015

           High     Low     precip  Snow    Forecast    Avg. Hi     Avg. Lo
Thu
1/1/2015    40°     14°     0 in    0 in    Cloudy      38°           23°
Fri
1/2/2015    42°     23°     0 in    0 in    Cloudy      38°           23°
Sat
1/3/2015    36°     21°     0.58 in 0 in    Cloudy      38°           23°
```

I have to read in the High/Low temps and the avg high/low temps. Here is the function I have down that could read in the file if there was only the numbers I need and no labeling:

```
Public Sub getNext4Ints(ByRef int1 As Integer, ByRef int2 As Integer, ByRef int3 As Integer, ByRef int4 As Integer)

    int1 = getNextInteger()

    int2 = getNextInteger()

    int3 = getNextInteger()

    int4 = getNextInteger()

End Sub

Public Function getNextInteger() As Integer

    Dim charInt As String
    Dim chr As String
    Static index As Integer = -1

    index += 1
    chr = numDat(index)

    While Asc(chr) < 48 Or Asc(chr) > 57
        index += 1
        chr = numDat(index)
    End While

    charInt = chr

    While Asc(chr) >= 48 And Asc(chr) <= 57
        index += 1
        chr = numDat(index)
        charInt += chr
    End While

    Return CInt(charInt)

End Function
```

Basically I am having trouble with only reading in what I need and skipping over the labels such as the date, precip, snow, and forecast. Sorry I am new to vb and can't seem to get around this. Thank you.

Comment: Is this vba or vb? Those are different languages

Comment: vb , I didnt know there was a difference and couldnt find a tag for visual basic

Comment: Is you file a Tab (or otherwise) delimited text file? If so it looks kike you can read each line checking if the first item is a date. If the first item is a date, parse the remaining items in the line for the data you want.